# Upgrading and buying RAMs

Tags: memory

Before I'm going to buy new pair of Rams I have a question about reliability when you do not buy the same Rams you have already in computer - I mean the same brand... etc. Of course it will have same specifications ( un/buffered, frequention, DDR type...) keep away or go for it? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you're building a high-end system with specific requirements, you do not need to match RAM brands, speeds, timings, or anything else besides the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

The brand/model doesn't make any difference as long type,speed,clock,etc match.

There are 2 exceptions to that rule:

1. If you have a system that uses dual-channel or triple-channel RAM, the RAM is best installed in pairs (or triples) of identical RAM strips.
2. Some computers are VERY picky about the brand/model of RAM and will ONLY work with RAM certified by the manufacturer. In that case a, in all other aspects compatible, RAM from another brand will usually not work. This type of pickiness usually only appears in hardware that is sold as "business" or "professional" grade. Consumer PC's are usually not that picky (but there exceptions).

Comment: Also, wouldn't affect long term reliability I suspect.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree.